# SAS to Hive Data copy

Tags: hive, sas

I have below scenario and hope could get help resolve the same please.

I am converting my SAS datasets to Hive tables. I am able to convert most of data types to corresponding datatypes in hive using proc contents on SAS table.
However, for some of the numeric columns in SAS, there is no format defined. It is just created as Num and contains both integers and decimals. All my logic was based on the format column in proc contents. For most of the columns it would have Num format'best32.' and based on formatd we define the decimal part. But in situation where it is just Num and contains both integers and decimals, Hive table is created with numeric column and decimals are rounded off in hive table.

Is there a way to know if a Num column in SAS dataset has integers or decimals or both and based on the outcome I can create corresponding column in Hive and copy data as is please ?

Comment: Does HIVE have a FLOAT type? Why not just use that?

Comment: I tried float, but challenge is it adds .0 to integers.. I want result to be saved as below         
2
1.23

Comment: 12, 12.0, 12.00, and 12.000000000 are the exact same number.  If you need to distinguish between '1' and '1.0' then store it as a character variable and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a test for being integer:

```
data test;
  input int dec;
cards;
1 10
2.0 11.1
3.0 12.2
4   13
;
run;

data result;
  set test end=eof nobs=nobs;
    array NN(i) int dec;
    array rr[2];

    do over NN;
     rr[i]+(NN=int(NN));
    end;

    if eof then do;
      do over NN;
       if rr[i] NE nobs then do;
          x = vname(NN);
          Put x " is decimal";
       end;
      end; 
      
    end;
run;
```

Comment: proc sql;

drop table test;
create table test (total_debt num);

insert into test values (10151162000000.00);
insert into test values (10151162000012.01);
insert into test values (1234.1232);

drop table dec;
create table dec (TOTAL_DEBT num format=30.2 informat=30.2 label='Total Debt')
;

insert into dec values (10151162000000.00);
insert into dec values (10151162000012.01);
insert into dec values (1234.1232);
quit;

Comment: proc sql;
select 
 total_Debt,
coalesce(max(lengthn(scan(put(total_Debt,best30.),2,"."))),0) as a
from work.dec;

select 
 total_Debt,
   coalesce(max(lengthn(scan(put(total_Debt,best.),2,"."))),0) as a

from work.test;
quit;

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing code. My next challenge is to identify max number of decimals in a column across all rows. I got below code from google , but not working as expected for below examples. could you please run below code in you sas session and help with correct functions that can work in my macro to identify number of decimals please ? P.S: I have used coalesce if that column has no rows and replaced with 0.